# how to give different names on tooltip for one series in highcharts R

Tags: r, highcharts

I made a bubble chart similar to the example code below (not a car guy, sorry if it doesn't make sense). In my case, I have a unique ID to each row of data that I would like shown in the tooltip of each bubble, along with the other data defined in the axis and size.

This example code I have made does not seem to show anything when I try to specify the car name of each bubble in the tooltip. But, when I replace the sprintf() argument for a simple string, it shows on all of the bubbles but not the other data described above.

Suggestions on doing this better or is there an answer to my problem?

```
library(highcharter)

df = data.frame(Car = row.names(mtcars), mtcars, row.names = NULL)

hchart(df, "bubble", hcaes(x = drat, y = wt, group = gear, size = mpg),
       tooltip = list(pointFormat = sprintf("Car: %s", df$Car)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be able to do this using the tooltip.formatter from the highcharts js API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

You can see a handy article on how to do it here: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR3UzztbrY4rdCbOw1W7DmSq4mWJswJZxIw-xOqGbjIRExj-gsuVEO2zM00

```
library('highcharter')
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type = "bubble",
    data = list(5, 4, 3, 5)
  ) %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
      var chart = this; chart.update({
         tooltip: {
              formatter: function () {
                  return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                      '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
              }
          }
      });
    }
    ")
  ))
```